# Why does 15.5 mod 5 = 0?

Tags: php, modulus

I understand 15 mod 5 = 0 because there is no remainder from the division.

But why does 15.5 mod 5 == 0 also? Isn't there .5 remaining?

```
$time = "15.5";
$interval = 5.0;
if($time % $interval == 0)
    echo "it's time!";
else
    echo "not time";

//Outputs: it's time!
```

Comment: @Thilo Appears to be PHP from the URL example ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

Use [`fmod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) if you want to preserve decimal remainders. (Thanks for the link, **Oli Charlesworth**, wasn't aware that such a function existed.)

Comment: @KevinDuke: It doesn't suck that much.  Use [`fmod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) instead.

Comment: @KevinDuke: I just typed in "modulus decimal". I'm no PHP expert either. I just use Google a lot. :)